# SQL - Removing duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've developed the following SQL.  There are basically 2 tables.  In the first part of this SQL I'm joining `table 1` to `table 2` and pulling all the records from `table 1` and the matching records from `table 1`.  I then do a `UNION` to the same thing but this time, I'm joining `table 2` to `table 1` and pulling all of the records from `table 2` and only the matching records from `table 1`.

The `UNION` in each half of the query is so I can get both fixed asset accounts and the accumulated depreciation accounts in the same column.

I need to do this because there could be data in `table 1` and not `table 2` and I need to make sure I get all of there differences.  As I expected, there are duplicate rows returned in the results.  I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I get rid of the duplicate results?
2. I'm calculating the difference in each half of the query.  Is there a better way or place to do this calculation?
3. Is a better way to do this SQL?

I appreciate your help with these questions?

```
SELECT
    a.FA_ACCT,
    a.ERACBR,
    a.deptid,
    a.FA_AMT,
    pgal.pstd_ttl_amt,
    CASE WHEN pgal.pstd_ttl_amt IS NULL THEN a.FA_AMT
    ELSE a.FA_AMT - pgal.pstd_ttl_amt END AS DIFF

FROM 

(SELECT 
            pdr.account_fa AS FA_ACCT,
            ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS ERACBR,
            pdr.deptid,
            SUM(pdr.COST) AS FA_Amt

FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'
--AND ( ? is null or soh.REGION_CD = ?)

GROUP BY FA_ACCT, ERACBR, deptid

UNION All

SELECT
pdr.account_ad AS FA_ACCT,
ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS ERACBR,
pdr.deptid,
SUM(pdr.depr_ltd) AS FA_Amt

FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'
--AND ( ? is null or soh.REGION_CD = ?)

GROUP BY FA_ACCT, ERACBR, deptid ) a

LEFT JOIN PSFS.PS_GL_ACCT_LDGR PGAL ON a.deptid =pgal.grp_br_ps_org_id
    AND a.fa_acct = pgal.acct_nbr
    AND pgal.fiscal_yr_mth_nbr = 201508

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6

UNION ALL  

SELECT 
pgal.acct_nbr AS FA_ACCT,
ir.erac_branch_lgcy_cd AS ERACBR,
pgal.grp_br_ps_org_id,
b.FA_AMT,
pgal.pstd_ttl_amt,

CASE WHEN b.fa_amt IS NULL THEN pgal.pstd_ttl_amt
    ELSE b.FA_AMT - pgal.pstd_ttl_amt END AS DIFF

FROM psfs.ps_gl_acct_ldgr pgal

LEFT JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION ir ON pgal.grp_br_ps_org_id = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1 

LEFT  JOIN 

    (SELECT 
            pdr.account_fa AS FA_ACCT,
            pdr.deptid,
            SUM(pdr.COST) AS FA_Amt

        FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

    WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
    AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
    AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
    AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
    AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'
    --AND ( ? is null or soh.REGION_CD = ?)

    GROUP BY FA_ACCT, deptid

UNION All

    SELECT
    pdr.account_ad AS FA_ACCT,
    pdr.deptid,
    SUM(pdr.depr_ltd) AS FA_Amt

    FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

    WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
    AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
    AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
    AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
    AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'
    --AND ( ? is null or soh.REGION_CD = ?)

    GROUP BY FA_ACCT, deptid) b

ON pgal.grp_br_ps_org_id = b.deptid
AND pgal.acct_nbr = b.fa_acct

WHERE pgal.fiscal_yr_mth_nbr = 201508
AND pgal.acct_nbr BETWEEN 130500 AND 160500   
AND ir.ody_group_cd = 'A0465'

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: The part that says 'GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6' seems odd to me.  I would expect that to possibly yield duplicates.  Also, your last UNION set introduces another chance to produce duplicates.  Have you isolated which of the sets (pre-union) are producing duplicates, or if the duplicates only appear after the UNION?

Comment: I changed the UNION ALL to UNION between the 2 main queries and that resolved my issue.  the SQL was running 1 query from table 1 to table and a second query from table 2 to table 1.  I'm doing this because it is possible (although) not likely that each table could have data that isn't on the other table.  I fully expected duplicates, I just needed to get rid of them.  Thanks for the reply.